# Is there an order to the Pokemon games chronologically?

Tags: pokemon-series

For all of the main Pokemon games since Pokemon Red and Blue, and all the way to today's X & Y, are the games in chronological order?

I'm genuinely curious as to if there's an storyline spanning through all the games? So in this case, assuming it goes R,B,Y --> LG,FR --> Ruby, Sapphire, Emerald --> Pearl, Diamond --> Black, White --> X & Y?  Or is it assumed that each game (in each respective region) happens right alongside other the games, timewise?

Comment: Well, it supposedly mirrors the show, where Ash travels through the regions, so if you put it in perspective of the show, the answer is yes.

Comment: @Despato I don't think it mirrors the show, because 1) the show has absolutely no progression and 2) the show is based on the game, not the other way around.

Comment: @Chippies: More relevent: in the game you start with an empty dex and fill it out.  In the show, Ash starts with a full dex.  Ergo, games come before show?  Also see: [Pokemon Origins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Origins).

Comment: @MooingDuck Ash is not the player character in the games, The main character in gen 1 was Red, in gen 2 it was Ethan (Or Cris as a female character in Crystal)

Comment: @Kevin: Correct. As I said, the player character (Red) fills out the dex, and then Ash from the movies later received a full dex from Oak. Also see: [Pokemon Origins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Origins)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As usual, [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/History_of_the_Pok%C3%A9mon_world#Contemporary_history) holds the answer:

(Fire) Red, (Leaf) Green, Blue and Yellow, as well as (Omega) Ruby, (Alpha) Sapphire and Emerald, are all simultaneous.

Three years later, (Heart) Gold, (Soul) Silver and Crystal, as well as Pearl, Diamond and Platinum happen.

Some time later, the events of Black and White transpire, and two years later, Black 2 and White 2 happen, contemporaneously to X and Y.

Comment: "This article contains fan speculation.
There is no solid evidence for or against some parts of this article." Bulbapedia is not a canon source, and the one citation anywhere on the page is a dead link.

Comment: A quick Google search confirms it on multiple websites http://m.imgur.com/pvba5Ur

Comment: @user2357112 The link on the citation isn't dead (at least, not anymore). It's a link to a tweet from matsumiyan on Twitter saying (translated): "Red and green ≒ RS → gold and silver ≒ DPPt → BW → BW2 ≒ XY". Exact years aren't given, but it at least confirms the order and which ones happened at the same time.

Answer (score -3):

Since playing X/Y the very beginning states that"3000 years ago, a great pokemon war" happened. There was a war in pokemon Red, Blue, Green, FireRed and LeafGreen. Therefore I believe that X/Y take place 3000 years in the future.

Then the fact that ORAS came out would disprove my theory. Since the Brendan there is the same Brendan that was in RBY and SPR. but it seems that Link from the Legend of Zelda all look the same. Or that the remakes take place in Different Universes. Since not much changed but either double battles were made or Mega Evolutions were found 3000 years early.

Comment: What "war" are you talking about from R, B, G, FR, LG? You might have to refresh my memory a little.

Comment: @DangerZone Lt. Surge mentions "the war." Fan speculation has taken this comment and run with it for all it's worth. This particular answer seems to be assuming there was only ever one war in all of history, and is entirely speculation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @MikeKellogg. And I was thinking the same thing.

Comment: its just what i think.